# How to create user in Google Admin with Service Account (server side)

Tags: python, google-api

I am trying to create a user in Google Admin via API
[(google admin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Og15.png)

Things I have done:

- create service account and credentials
- installed sdk lib
- read multiple docs on service account/Oauth credentials, google sdk authen., admin api
- code

```
class Gcp:

    def __init__(self):
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "core/gcp/XXX.json"
        read_domain_scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.domain.readonly'
        admin_user_scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'
        read_ou_scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit.readonly'
        SCOPES = [read_domain_scope, admin_user_scope, read_ou_scope,]
        self.credential = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

    def list_user(self):
        res = googleapiclient.discovery.build('users', 'v1', credentials=self.credential)
        return 'OK'
```

Problems:
I can not find a document which specify how I can create user in google admin via SDK, I mean I've found the REST api [doc](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest#rest-resource:-users)

But I seems that I need to authenticate through OAuth2 for the REST calls.
Is there a way to get this (create user and assign domain/organization unit) done with just service account credential file with SDK?